# How to add header as parameter in ajax call rest web service request in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to add header as parameter in ajax call rest web service  request in sencha touch

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can add header in the sencha touch AJAX call,

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'myUrl',

   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },

   callback: function(options, success, response) {
      console.log(response.responseText);
   }
});
```